# How to make a for/foreach loop on github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I would like to implement a git action that, given a draft PR, when clicking "ready for review" button, will dismiss all reviews(that happened during the draft stage..).

I see no dismiss all API for Github, so I would have to list all reviews on the PR, and dismiss them all, one by one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could use a composite action to do this with shell bash, with a first step extracting all the reviews from the PR, and the second step with the for each loop to dismiss each one. I guess you'll probably need a PAT as action input to dismiss the reviews. Using a composite action with shell bash will allow the action to work on ubuntu, macos and windows runners. Here is an example of a personnal action using composite shell with bash as reference (https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/test-cli-commands-action/blob/main/action.yml)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yeah, that concept of:
echo "::set-output name=result::$(echo $result)"
and then: 
steps.comparision.outputs.result was very helpful! thanks!

Comment: Did it help you finding a solution Tom? if yes, i could maybe add it as official answer 

Comment: @Yes, it did! thank you!